# Como manusear iframes em uma lista?

Tags: javascript, html, lista, iframe, youtube

Estou tentando agrupar uma série de vídeos do YouTube no meu blog pessoal, todos os vídeos estão dentro de uma tag iframe, por exemplo:

```
<iframe class="YTvideo" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="344"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LeAkYuMDVGY?wmode=opaque" width="459"></iframe>
```

Estou tentando manipular 4 vídeos e tentar capturar quantas vezes cada vídeo é tocado com o seguinte código.

```
//importando biblioteca YT
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubeIframesAPIReady(){
  var frame = document.querySelectorAll('iframe[src*="youtube"]');
  var player = [frame.length];
  for(var i=0; i < frame.length; i++){
    //Habilitar a jsapi para poder manusear os controles do player
    frame[i].src += "&enablejsapi=true";

    //incorporando cada iframe para um espaço no array de players
    player[i] = new YT.Player(frame[i]);
    player[i].addEventListener('onStateChange', onPlayerStateChange);
  }
}
var onPlayerStateChange = function(event){
  console.log(event.data);
}
```

O navegador me reporta o seguinte erro:

> googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/962985656/?aid=AAA…N5vJSNXPEwA&foc_id=sooa4yRKGN_zEE8iknghZA&label=followon_view&ptype=view:1
>   GET
>   https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/962985656/…3DN5vJSNXPEwA&foc_id=sooa4yRKGN_zEE8iknghZA&label=followon_view&ptype=view
>   net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT